# Java can't connect to database via SSH tunnel

Tags: java, maven, ssh, mariadb

I am developing a small java utility with which I have to retrieve data on a remote mariadb database reachable at IP_1, so the recovered data must be manipulated and saved on another database, always mariadb, on a server reachable at IP_2.
To connect to the database reachable on IP_2, using navicat, I connect in ssh to the server and then to the database as localhost. (and the connection happens correctly)
I then looked for guides on how to do this in java maven, and defined the program.
Nonetheless I can also connect correctly with Java in SSH, then when I have to communicate with the DB and open the connection, I get the following error:

`java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host: address = (host = 192.168.100.144) (port = 3366) (type = primary). Connection refused`

Do you have any suggestions or advice? I have no idea how to fix it

- mycode:
  App.java

```
package mspay.helpdesk;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Recupero richieste di assistenza tecnica!");

        // Apertura connessione SSH
        try {
            final JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "IP_2", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");
            final Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            session.setPortForwardingL(3366, "IP_2", 3306);

            if (session.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Connessione SSH stabilita con successo!");
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Utility u = new Utility("IP_1", "user", "password", "name");
                u.takeCassettiAttivi();

                ResultSet ca = u.getComuni();
                try {
                    while (ca.next()) {
                        System.out.println("Eleborazione del comune di: " + ca.getString(2));
                        u.takeRichiesteAssistenza(ca.getString(3));
                        ResultSet ri = u.getRichieste();
                        u.saveRichiesteAssistenza(ri, ca.getString(2).replace("'", " "));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Impossibile stabilire connessione SSH!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (JSchException jsche) {
            jsche.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- Class Utility.java

```
package mspay.helpdesk;

import java.util.*;
//gestione sql
import java.sql.*;
//gestione files
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Utility {

   static private String host;
   static private String uname;
   static private String pwd;
   static private String db;
   static Connection c = null;
   static private ResultSet ca;
   static private ResultSet rich;

   public Utility(String h, String usr, String pass, String database) {
      host = h;
      uname = usr;
      pwd = pass;
      db = database;
   }

   // recuperiamo i cassetti attivi
   public void takeCassettiAttivi() {
      try {
         c = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mariadb://" + host + ":3306/" + db + "?" + "user=" + uname + "&password=" + pwd + "");

         String sql = "SELECT * FROM `cassetti` where abilitato = 1";
         Statement st = c.createStatement();
         ca = st.executeQuery(sql);
         c.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

      }

   }

   // recuperiamo le richieste di assistenza tecnica
   public void takeRichiesteAssistenza(String database) {
      try {
         c = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mariadb://" + host + ":3306/" + database + "?" + "user=" + uname + "&password=" + pwd + "");

         // recupero le richieste di assistenza tecnica
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_richiestatecnica` WHERE tecData BETWEEN '2022-10-19' AND '2022-10-21' ORDER BY idTEC DESC";
         Statement st = c.createStatement();
         rich = st.executeQuery(sql);
         System.out.println("Operazione di recupero delle richieste avvenuta con successo, COMUNE DI :" + database);
         c.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   // salviamo le richieste sul database
   public void saveRichiesteAssistenza(ResultSet richieste, String comune) {

      System.out.println("Salvataggio delle richieste nel repository centrale, COMUNE DI :" + comune);
      try {
         String database = "dbname";
         c = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mariadb://IP_2:3366/" + database + "?user=db_user&password=db_password");

         if (c.isValid(0)) {
            System.out.println("Connessione al server ubuntu avvenuta con successo");
            try {
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
               }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }

         // effettuo l'insert delle richieste all'interno del DB di helpdesk
         if (!comune.equals("Civitanova Marche")) {
            while (richieste.next()) {
               StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                     "INSERT INTO richieste_assistenza (comune, nominativo, cfpiva, email, oggetto, richiesta, mailcomune, datarichiesta, orarichiesta, stato) VALUES (");
               sql.append("'" + comune + "', '" + richieste.getString(4).replace("'", " ") + "', '"
                     + richieste.getString(5) + "', '" + richieste.getString(6) + "', '" + richieste.getString(7)
                     + "', '" + richieste.getString(8) + "', '" + richieste.getString(14) + "', '"
                     + richieste.getString(2) + "', '" + richieste.getString(3) + "', 'TODO')");
               System.out.println("QUERY DI UPDATE");
               System.out.println(sql.toString());
               Statement st = c.createStatement();
               st.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
            }
            c.close();
         } else {
            while (richieste.next()) {
               StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                     "INSERT INTO richieste_assistenza (comune, nominativo, cfpiva, email, oggetto, richiesta, mailcomune, datarichiesta, orarichiesta, stato) VALUES (");
               sql.append("'" + comune + "', '" + richieste.getString(4).replace("'", " ") + "', '"
                     + richieste.getString(11) + "', '" + richieste.getString(5) + "', '" + richieste.getString(6)
                     + "', '" + richieste.getString(7) + "', '" + richieste.getString(13) + "', '"
                     + richieste.getString(2) + "', '" + richieste.getString(3) + "', 'TODO')");
               System.out.println("QUERY DI UPDATE");
               System.out.println(sql.toString());
               Statement st = c.createStatement();
               st.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
            }
            c.close();
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public ResultSet getComuni() {
      return ca;
   }

   public ResultSet getRichieste() {
      return rich;
   }

}
```

Comment: `saveRichiesteAssistenza` specifies IP_2:3366, which does not use the SSH tunnel. Since you say you want to use the tunnel, have the DB driver connect to localhost:3366 (or 127.0.0.1:3366) which is where the tunnel is listening, and the tunnel will relay to IP_2:3306 which is presumably where the DBMS is (not 3366).

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, if i understood, can i connect to IP_2:3306? Because connection to IP_2:3306 works fine via navicat or similar DB manager.
But i've tried to connect via IP_2:3306 and i've the same `Connection Refused` error

Comment: If IP_2 is reachable from your system and accepts incoming connections to 3306 yes, but generally people only set up SSH tunnels when those conditions aren't met. You say you are already using the tunnel, and I assumed you had a reason to do so and weren't just deliberately wasting everybody's time.